# Append string to another string after a specified character

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `a="<tr>i'm working in C#<tr/> abcdefghjiklmnopqr ii oo yy uu hh gg rr"`, and `b="<td>Finish</td></tr>"`. I need string `a` as

```
  a="<tr>i'm working in C#<tr/> <td>Finish</td></tr> abcdefghjiklmnopqr ii oo yy uu hh gg rr".
```

---

How do we append string in string like above? I asked a same question earlier which was wrong. 
Here will have to find for first ">" charcter and append b in a.

Please help.

Comment: And these html tags are intended there? You want to append "Finish", but the resulting string contains additional characters (tags).

Comment: @Andrew:thanks. No I have added tags like that. it`s not displaying.

Comment: Are you sure you want two <tr/> tags?  Maybe you don't want the first one?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `String.Format`:

```
string a = "i'm working in C#";
string b = "Finish";
a = String.Format("<tr>{0}<tr/> <td>{1}</td></tr>",a,b);
```

See here for how to use the first parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Comment: This is correct, but since it's HTML you'd likely want to make sure a and b are html escaped before tossing them in. see `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`

Answer (score 1):

If you have just those two strings, you could just append them like this:

```
a = "<tr>" + a  + "<tr/> <td>" + b + "</td></tr>"; // But please use valid markup.
```

Or, stealing nphx's idea:

```
a = string.Format("<tr>{0}<tr/> <td>{1}</td></tr>", a, b);
```

If, however, you want to insert something inside a string, you use the [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx) method. Feel free to be creative about how to get the index for the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("{0} {1}", a, b);
```

Makes the code more readable than simple concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

[string.Format](https://www.google.com/search?q=msdn%20string.format&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)("{0} {1}/td>", "i`m working in C#", "Finish");